# How push all system.out.print to HTML page

Tags: java, servlets

The title may not be clear enough, but actually my case is quite simple.

There is a jar that gets a certain task done. Now there is servlet that calls the jar and a user can access the servlet and request the task to be done. I want to push all system.out.prints in the jar, which shows processing progress information, to the HTML page returned. Any solution? Thanks!

Comment: See [`System.setOut(PrintStream)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut%28java.io.PrintStream%29) but note that seems like an hack.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewThompson! At a brief look this way looks good. Would you elaborate why it seems like an hack?

Comment: One reason that this may feel like a hack:  I'm pretty sure that you are redirecting System.out for the entire jvm.  In a servlet scenario, are you really sure that you are the only process running in the JVM? I think the problem here is that you won't be able to only capture the prints from code in the jar - you are going to get all of the output of the entire JVM...

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [`System.setOut(PrintStream)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/). You could set the output stream to the servlet's output stream. Then, any further references to `System.out` would actually reference your HTML.

Comment: I need it to work more like system.out. I mean when I print a line of words, I need it to update on the webpage immediately. How can I use Ajax to do this?